# Error en link al abrir en popup

Tags: php

Sabrian identificar donde se encuentra el error?

Asi funciona:

```
   public function upme_favorite_posts_list($atts){
    global $post,$wpdb,$upme_options;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'number_of_posts'   => 200 ,
        'featured_image' => 'no',
        'user_id' => 'no',
      ), $atts ) );

    $content = '';

    if($user_id != 'no'){
        $user_id = (int) $user_id;
        if( $user_id == '0' ){
            if(is_user_logged_in()){
                $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

                $sql  = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT upf.*,p.post_excerpt,p.guid FROM {$wpdb->prefix}upme_post_features as upf inner join  $wpdb->posts as p on p.ID = upf.post_id  WHERE upf.favorite_status = %d AND upf.user_id = %d", 1 , $user_id );
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }else{
            $sql  = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT upf.*,p.post_excerpt,p.guid FROM {$wpdb->prefix}upme_post_features as upf inner join  $wpdb->posts as p on p.ID = upf.post_id  WHERE upf.favorite_status = %d AND upf.user_id = %d", 1 , $user_id );
        }

        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        if($result){

            $featured_enabled_types = (array) $upme_options->upme_settings['featured_image_enabled_types'];
            $featured_image_setting_status = in_array('favorite',$featured_enabled_types);  
            $featured_image_status = ($featured_image == 'no' || $featured_image_setting_status);

            $content .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">';
            foreach($result as $row){


                if($featured_image_status){

                    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($row->post_id), 'thumbnail');
                    $image_src = upme_url . 'img/default-post-thumbnail.png';
                    if($upme_options->upme_settings['favorite_default_featured_image'] != ''){
                        $image_src = $upme_options->upme_settings['favorite_default_featured_image'];
                    }
                    if (is_array($image_attributes) && ('' != $image_attributes[0])) {
                        $image_src = $image_attributes[0];
                    }

                    $content .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">


                                    <span>

  <a target="_blank" href="'.$row->guid.'">'.$row->post_excerpt.'</a>
                                    </span>

                            </div>';

                }else{
                    $content .= '<div class="upme-main upme-main-">


                                    <span>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="'.$row>guid.'">'.$row->post_excerpt.'</a>
                                    </span>

                            </div>';
                }



            }
            $content .= '</div><div class="upme-clear"></div>';
        }
  //            echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

yo estoy reemplazando esta linea:

```
     <a target="iframe1" href="'.$row->guid.'">'.$row->post_excerpt.'</a>
```

por esta:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('.$row->guid.','_blank','width=900,height=300');">'.$row->post_excerpt.'</a>
```

pero me tira error y no puedo abrir wordpress..
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me aprece que es porque no estas escapando (\\) las comillas simples (`'`). Intenta hacerlo así: `echo '<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('.$row->guid.',\'_blank\',\'width=900,height=300\');">'.$row->post_excerpt.'</a>';`

Comment: @Marcos Gracias por tu rapida respuesta. Lo intente pero no funciona. Si le saco la palabra echo me deja visualizarla pero me figura asi entre renglon y renglon una coma y el enlace no funciona (aparece en barra de estado: javascript: void(0) )

Comment: Por favor, pon el código completo (en PHP), sólo con la parte que pones no se ve el problema (que seguramente es un asunto de escapar unas comillas en el window.open). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Además, sería de ayuda que pusieras el error que recibes en la consola de JavaScript (que seguramente dice que la variable no existe o un error de sintaxis al faltar las comillas correctas).